# sitecore redirect manager not working with external links

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, sitecore, external

I installed the SITECORE REDIRECT MANAGER from the marketplace and I'm trying to create a redirect. It works fine with the "Insert Link" option that points to items inside the tree. However I need to open a external link and it doesn't work. I've tried several external links and I tried to change Sitecore.SharedSource.RedirectManager.UrlValidation configuration but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What is the URL that you are redirecting to?  We have several sites that point to other sites not yet on Sitecore and they work, but we had to set it up in the configuration to allow IIS to handle other incoming extensions and I think that you need to allow IIS to handle that for outgoing as well since its generating the link for you... so it makes sense that it might go the other way around too. Here's what we added to one of the patch config files for this type of thing and it works for us.

```
<preprocessRequest help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.PreprocessRequestProcessor">
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <patch:delete />
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx, asp, pdf, htm, html</param>
        <param desc="Blocked extensions (comma separated)">*</param>
        <param desc="Blocked extensions that stream files (comma separated)">*</param>
        <param desc="Blocked extensions that do not stream files (comma separated)" />
    </processor>
</preprocessRequest>
```

Comment: Thanks divamatrix, I had read something similar and I tried to add extensions and play around with IIS but no luck. I solve with a different solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed this to get redirects for sources with .php extensions working correctly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the "Sitecore Redirect Manager" supports external URLs.

You may want to look into a different module written by ParTech that **does** support external links: [URL Rewriter](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/URL_Rewriter.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Craig, Sitecore Redirect Manager should support external links. At least for Sitecore 6.5 but I'm now working with Sitecore 7.1. However I've manage to solve this with a different approach.